# Running a FOR loop in AWS SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I need to stop few containers in an EC2 instance and then once they are stopped I need to shutdown the EC2 instance.
my simple loop looks like below:-

`` 'for s in `sudo docker ps -aq`; do sudo docker stop $s;done' ``
the actual for oneliner is like below:-

```
for s in `sudo a_custom_script another_old_docker_based_script | grep ^a_pattern`;do sudo a_custom_script "solution_start $s";done
```

My Lambda script looks like this:-

```
import json
import boto3
import time


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-2')
    response = ssm.send_command( InstanceIds=['i-0d2a7492c0a721c19'], DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", Parameters={'commands': ['for s in `sudo docker ps -aq`; do sudo docker stop $s";done']},)
    
    time.sleep(2)
    cmd= response['Command']['CommandId']
    response = ssm.get_command_invocation(CommandId=cmd, 
    InstanceId='i-0d2a7492c0a721c19')
    return response
```

the 'Status' field in response always shows me "InProgress" and I am not sure if the containers are in stopped state.

Because of this I am unable to determine if I should stop the EC2 instance.

Please help.

Comment: There is some rouge quotation mark `$s"`?

Comment: Sorry!! removed it. This still does not work.

Comment: Enable cloudwatch logs for run command and inspect the logs. Also when you run the command manually on the instance, does it work?

Comment: Yes @Marcin, the for loop does work manually.

Comment: Have to go to basic, if CW logs don't show anything. For example, can you just run basic for loop, without any docker? If yes, then add looping over docker ids, and just echo them. If this works, add other element and so on, until you identify what breaks your run command.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you go to SSM console and check, do the commands successfuly complete?

Comment: I ask as I don't see any pooling loop in your lambda. Why would you assume that it takes 2 seconds to complete the run command?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, it worked. I had to give a long sleep time like 300seconds for the ssm to come back and tell that it succeeded. Actually the for loop with the custom command take about 240-250 seconds and I have time'd it in the machine itself. What polling loop do you suggest here Marcin. I know keeping 300seconds is not a very elegant solution.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I would like to add  an answer for future reference :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue reported was caused by not giving the run-command enough time to complete. Thus it appeared as being `inProgress` for long.

The solution was to wait for its completion a bit longer.

To reduce guessing of how long to wait, a basic **for-loop** could be used to check iteratively progress of the command.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
while True:
  
  time.sleep(2)
   
  cmd= response['Command']['CommandId']
  status = cmd['status']

  if status == 'inProgress':
    print('Keep waiting for the run command...')
    continue

  print('Command is no long in "inPorgress" state')
```